# Does SQL always applies WHERE after JOIN, and is it fast?

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, where-clause

Say, I have two big tables - A and B.

I want to take 3 rows from A and join them to 3 rows from B:

```
select * from A join B
on A.externalKey = B.externalKey
where A.id in (1, 2, 3)
```

Will SQL (namely, PostgreSQL) recognize that it's faster to apply WHERE before JOIN, because the condition depends only on A's parameters?

If no, is `with A as (select * from A where ...) select * from A join B` faster and the best way to do that?

Comment: Have you tried timing it out? I would assume the latter is faster. Every time you do a table join you are doing a cartesian product, which will create an n * m rowed table, then it filters down based on your join condition and the where clause would happen after the join. I am not familiar with how postgres is implemented, but just judging by relational algebra the latter would be faster.

Comment: Haven't yet. But yep, that's exactly what I'm thinking about. Like, if you put the whole condition into `on`: `A.externalKey = B.externalKey and A.id in (1, 2, 3)`, you'll filter n * m rows, whereas for the latter you'll filter n + m rows.
But it looks like a common problem, for which there must be a simple solution.

Comment: Try `EXPLAIN`, I would expect both queries to be executed the same way

Comment: "Will SQL recognize that it's faster to apply WHERE before JOIN", for every query the optimizer calculates the best way to execute the query. It all depends on statistics, indexes and so on.

Comment: That `IN` operator right there is a performance killer. A less elegant, rephrased query can perform much faster.

Comment: But to respond to your question, there's no clear cut rule. The database optimizer will try to guess which strategy is better to produce the result you want and will use it. Moreover the strategy can change in the future without notice.

Comment: @TheImpaler: I don't think the IN operator here will be a performance killer. If there is an index on a.id it will be used

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I tend to think that if `id` is `int` then yes, a Range Scan can be quite performant. Otherwise an Index Skip Scan can do the trick. In the worst case scenario a Table Scan will be used.

Comment: [internal implementation of database Queries](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3022081/3404097) etc etc etc

Comment: Without the query plan and the execution result, it's impossible to tell anything about some performance issue. Use EXPLAIN(ANALYZE, VERBOSE, BUFFERS) for your SELECT statement, and not just EXPLAIN.

Comment: That `IN` operator is just an example of 'some condition for elements that depends only on A's values'